# Blank if row doesnt exist

Tags: sql

I have the following code.  On some occasions there will be no t1.LineNo = 2 so I want Val2 to just be null or blank.  But I cant get it to work

```
select
    MOTRAN_HAJobFile.JobNumber
    ,MOTRAN_HAExtraChg.Description,MOTRAN_HAExtraChg.Value

    ,***(select t1.Value from MOTRAN_HAExtraChg t1
where MOTRAN_HAExtraChg.JobUniqueKey = t1.JobUniqueKey
and t1.LineNo = 2)  as  Val2***

from
    MOTRAN_HAJobFile
    left outer join
    MOTRAN_HAExtraChg
    on MOTRAN_HAExtraChg.JobUniqueKey = MOTRAN_HAJobFile.UniqueKey
where
    MOTRAN_HAJobFile.JobNumber = '235416'
```

EDITED

```
Job              line        Description                     Value
235416             1          Sunday Collection               325
235416             2         Rush Charge                     82
```

this is the table but my code makes it like this

```
Job        Description               Value     Description2     Value 2
235416    Sunday Collection           325      Rush Charge     82
```

the line 2 will not always exist which is my problem I just want it to then leave description 2 and value 2 blank

Comment: If you are using sql server try using isnull() if you are using mysql then use ifnull()

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work?   What are you getting for Val2 if not "null or blank"???

Comment: If t1.LineNo = 2 doesn't exist Val2 will already be null.  Which means that the issue is probably something else such as your relationship/joins.  But I would recommend posting some sample data and expected result so that we can see what you want

Comment: if I put the isnull in
select MOTRAN_HAJobFile.JobNumber,MOTRAN_HAExtraChg.Description,MOTRAN_HAExtraChg.Value,
/*(select t.Description from MOTRAN_HAExtraChg t
 where MOTRAN_HAExtraChg.JobUniqueKey = t.JobUniqueKey
 and t.LineNo = 2) as  Descrip2,*/
 isnull((select t1.Value from MOTRAN_HAExtraChg t1
 where MOTRAN_HAExtraChg.JobUniqueKey = t1.JobUniqueKey
 and t1.LineNo = 2) ,0) as  Val2
from MOTRAN_HAJobFile left outer join MOTRAN_HAExtraChg on MOTRAN_HAExtraChg.JobUniqueKey = MOTRAN_HAJobFile.UniqueKey
where MOTRAN_HAJobFile.JobNumber = '235416'
and MOTRAN_HAExtraChg.LineNo = 1

Comment: You can (and should) [edit] your post instead of trying to put code into comments.

Comment: I have edited my original post

Comment: Unreproducible.   It is not possible for the code you posted to produce the results you say you are getting.   Post your actual code or your actual results.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database) are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Comment: Did you mean if your data is like this 

Job              line        Description                     Value
235416             1          Sunday Collection               325
235416             2         Rush Charge                     82    
235417             1          Sunday Collection               400

The result would be like this?

Job        Description               Value     Description2     Value 2
235416    Sunday Collection           325      Rush Charge     82  
235417    Sunday Collection           400

Answer (score 0):

sample table and data

```
CREATE TABLE jobfile
(job VARCHAR(6),
 line INT,
 description VARCHAR(50),
 value INT
)

INSERT INTO jobfile
VALUES ('235416',1,'Sunday Collection',325);

INSERT INTO jobfile
VALUES ('235416',2,'Rush Charge',82);

INSERT INTO jobfile
VALUES ('100001',1,'Sunday Collection',900);

job     line    description         value
235416  1       Sunday Collection   325
235416  2       Rush Charge         82
100001  1       Sunday Collection   900
```

query

```
SELECT DISTINCT jf.job,
       (SELECT description FROM jobfile WHERE job = jf.job AND line = 1) AS description,
       (SELECT value FROM jobfile WHERE job = jf.job AND line = 1) AS value,
       (SELECT description FROM jobfile WHERE job = jf.job AND line = 2) AS description2,
       (SELECT value FROM jobfile WHERE job = jf.job AND line = 2) AS value2
  FROM jobfile jf
```

sample result

```
job     description         value       description2    value2
100001  Sunday Collection   900         NULL            NULL
235416  Sunday Collection   325         Rush Charge     82
```